# How to access camera and micphone in android?

Tags: android, video, capture, v4l2

I want to write a android progrom,now i access the codec via the openmax by use jni in android's ui,I found there is no video  audio source or framebuffer in openmax components.My cell phone is qualcomm's msm7227 platform. in the qualcomm's website it says there is an amr codec int the SOC.

can i use V4L2 to access the camera and directy access the audio device like /dev/XX to capture audio data?

for example i want to capture a pic and encode it,first I allocate a buffer,fill the buffer with data by V4L2 then pass the address and other paremeters  to openmax video encoder componenet. i don't know is it a good way.

some one has experience can help me ?

by the way,the java is very slow,i want to code in C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

Don't just assume that Java is slow. I would recommend to try it in Java first, and then rewrite performance-critical parts in C++ once you've determined that your app is not fast enough.

The good thing about Java is that you can use the [`Camera` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) and [media classes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) directly, and they're pretty easy to use.

Comment: I don't know how to pass a point of chat arrays via the JNI to c function.